# CakePHP slow output, but query appears to be up to par 

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, benchmarking

Most of the outcome of what I am about to say is obvious, but I am looking for any additional configuration options or suggestions that might be available in the core or other modifications I can make to the script:

1. I switched my CakePHP app from development to production servers.
2. The queries I am testing take 2x time to process on the new server (about 10-12 seconds). For this test, I am actually counting the screen result load time. So from the second the submit button is pressed to the actual visual output results are completed.
3. My query output by CakePHP debug is (same exact query):

-- Development: 132 queries took 5 ms
-- Production:  132 queries took 53 ms.

It's clear that the queries are running much different in speed, but even the slower result is under a second!

It appears the slow down is the network or processor, but I am not seasoned enough in MySQL benchmarks w/ CakePHP to know if this is a Controller load issue or an actual MySQL issue. The fact that the results in the slower are 53ms does not lead me to believe my MySQL query is slow, it appears its somewhere in the actual output where the slowdown is happening..

Here is a link to a full MySQL query debug dump:
http://notepub.com/#fb=&note=185197

I've tried removing sections of the query, changing my join methods, and I am also using containable for the output results. I am going to continue testing.. Thanks for any feedback or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is speculation more than an answer, but it might help you anyways:

Looking at your log, there's really only one query that's taking any time, and its:

```
SELECT `Zip`.`id`, `Zip`.`title`, `PlansZip`.`id`, `PlansZip`.`plan_id`, `PlansZip`.`zip_id` FROM `zips` AS `Zip` JOIN `plans_zips` AS `PlansZip` ON (`PlansZip`.`plan_id` IN (253, 774, 137, 505, 114, 260, 501, 841, 268, 239, 497, 762, 768, 246, 123, 750, 756, 130, 886, 836, 839, 315, 331, 299) AND `PlansZip`.`zip_id` = `Zip`.`id`) ORDER BY `Zip`.`title` ASC
```

I think the reason it's taking so long is the way you're joining those two tables. I think you'll find something like this would be much faster:

```
SELECT `Zip`.`id`, `Zip`.`title`, `PlansZip`.`id`, `PlansZip`.`plan_id`, `PlansZip`.`zip_id` FROM `zips` AS `Zip` JOIN `plans_zips` AS `PlansZip` ON `PlansZip`.`zip_id` = `Zip`.`id`
WHERE `PlansZip`.`plan_id` IN (253, 774, 137, 505, 114, 260, 501, 841, 268, 239, 497, 762, 768, 246, 123, 750, 756, 130, 886, 836, 839, 315, 331, 299) ORDER BY `Zip`.`title` ASC
```

I did a comparable query in my own database, and found using the second method reduced the time required to run the query by a pretty significant factor.

The other question I'd put forward is whether or not your dev system is a mirror of the production system. If there's a ton more records in your prod system, you could just be seeing slow queries failing to scale up. What's the difference between the number of records returning on vs production? Even if SQL isn't the problem, it could be lagging from having to transmit a large amount of data or even rendering it on the screen.

Comment: I removed my last comment, because I don't think my SQL was correct on my tests. I posted my current code below, and I'm trying to translate and tweak that to meet what you are suggesting. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem I am running into is my query is done CakePHP style, and I am working out how to translate what you have.

This is my original:

```
array(
        'joins'      => array(
            array(
                'table'      => 'plans_zips',
                'alias'      => 'PZips',
                'type'       => 'inner',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Plan.id = PZips.plan_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table'      => 'zips',
                'alias'      => 'Zips',
                'type'       => 'inner',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Zips.id = PZips.zip_id')
            ),   
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Query 129 retrieves 10563 rows, it is natural to cause some (network?) traffic for such an amount of rows
2. If you want to speed up your queries you can try adding indexes to the following fields:
   PlansZip.plan_id
   PlansZip.zip_id
3. Restructure your query as user470714 suggested